# How to debug view not updating in angular 5

Tags: angular, meteor, angular-meteor

I am using Meteor with angular 5.0.5. Meteor uses websocket.

I often run into the situations when data from server is loaded and component fields has been updated but still view(dom) has not reflected changes until I click anywhere.

I have read about change detection and angular zones. View does updates even when after updating field I have called `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`,  `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck`, `ApplicationRef.tick` or updated field in angular zone using `this.zone.run(() => {...variable gets updated here})`

What are the ways to debug this kind of issues.

EDIT:
I have used MeteorObservable(which runs everything in angular zone) as well tried without MeteorObservable but running manually in angular zone. Below is the example

Component js file(changeDetection is set to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`)

```
ngOnInit() {
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    this.company = Companies.findOne();
    this.zone.run(() => {
      if(this.company) this.excluded_ips = this.company.excluded_ips;
      //here i have also tried detectChanges(), markForCheck() appref.tick() as well
    });
  });
}
```

Component template which uses another library(ngx-chips)

```
<tag-input 
    theme='minimal'
    inputClass="tag_input"
    [placeholder]="ip_placeholder"
    [validators]="validators"
    [errorMessages]="errorMessages"
    [modelAsStrings]="true"
    [ngModel]="excluded_ips"
    (onRemove)="onExcludedIPRemoved($event)"
    (onAdd)="onExcludedIPAdded($event)" #input>
</tag-input>
```

It does not reflect correct list of IPs whenever data in `excluded_ips` is updated.

I was not looking for just a solution but also a way to debug why it happening. I am ready to read more about angular or debug into angular code.

Comment: How are you fetching data from the server? It should happen automatically unless you have disabled zones.

Comment: I have not disabled zones, and I am getting data via websockets implemented by meteor framework. It happens sometimes and I want to know a good way to debug. I am ready to dive into relavant angular code.

Comment: Could you create a reproduction with `meteor-rxjs`?

Comment: I was able to reproduce only in my codebase. When I tried to reproduce in a sample by taking out only relavant code, it was working! For the workaround now i have simulated a click but still interested in knowing the root cause. @Urigo

Answer (score 1):

Make use of angular's `var | async` pipe, I also recommend using MeteorObservable for working with Angular 2+, which I'm almost certain you're using.

Can you post an example of your code?

Service.js

```
public getCategories(): ObservableCursor<ProductCategories> {
    if (!!this.categoriesSubscription) {
        this.categoriesSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.categoriesSubscription = MeteorObservable.subscribe('categories').subscribe();
    return CategoriesCollection.find({});
}
```

Component.js

```
categories: ObservableCursor<ProductCategories>;
constructor(){
    // Below should probably be set on ngOnInit()
    this.categories = this.productService.getCategories();
}
```

Component.html

```
<md-select placeholder="Categoría" class="clean lookupCategory" [formControl]="categoryId" flex="50"><md-option  [value]="''">Todos</md-option><md-option *ngFor="let cat of categories | async" [value]="cat._id">{{ cat.name }}</md-option></md-select>
```

Comment: I have updated the questions to add more details. Thanks a lot